# Difference between ChangeNotifierProvider and ScopedModel in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to have an explanation of the difference between [Provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)(with usage of [ChangeNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier-class.html) and [ChangeNotifierProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProvider-class.html)) and [Scoped Model package](https://pub.dev/packages/scoped_model) in Flutter.

After looking at these two methods of managing the state of the application, I was lost because I didn't find any substantial differences in the approach to code writing.

**Scoped Model package usage:**

```
class CounterModelWithScopedModel extends Model {
  int _counter = 0;
  int get counter => _counter;

  void increment() {
    _counter++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class CounterAppWithScopedModel extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ScopedModel<CounterModelWithScopedModel>(
      model: new CounterModelWithScopedModel(),
      child: new Column(children: [
        new ScopedModelDescendant<CounterModelWithScopedModel>(
          builder: (context, child, model) => new Text('${model.counter}'),
        ),
        new Text("Another widget that doesn't require scoped model")
      ])
    );
  }
}
```

**Provider package usage:**

```
class CounterModelWithChangeNotifierProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _counter = 0;
  int get counter => _counter;

  void increment() {
    _counter++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class CounterAppWithChangeNotifierProvider extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ChangeNotifierProvider(
      builder: (context) => CounterModelWithChangeNotifierProvider(),
      child: new Column(children: [
        new Consumer<CounterModelWithChangeNotifierProvider>(
          builder: (context, model, child) => new Text('${model.counter}')
        ),
        new Text("Another widget that doesn't require consume")
      ])
    );
  }
}
```

Now assume that we have another widget that trigger the notification with `increment();` of `CounterModelWithChangeNotifierProvider` and `CounterAppWithScopedModel` and cause the widgets to be rebuilt.

I have approached flutter recently and I am quite confused about the management of the application state, I started with Notifier but after seeing that there are an infinite number of ways for do that I do not know what to do. What do you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TD;DR:

`provider` is not `scoped_model` but can be used to mimic a `scoped_model` architecture.

---

`scoped_model` is an architecture, based on a subclass of `Listenable`: `Model`, that is now built-in Flutter under the name of `ChangeNotifier`

`provider` is not an architecture, but instead a mean to pass state and manage it.
It *can* be used to make a `scoped_model`-like architecture, but it *can* do something else too.

Comment: "but it can do something else too", like what?

Comment: @Wecherowski It's kinda broad. But for example, the library `bloc` depends on provider. And Mobx uses it too. But they are both completely unrelated to scoped_model

Answer (score 0):

**Provider** is a complete dependency injection solution, with some very powerful provider types that take care of boilerplate things like managing streams for instance. Whereas **ScopedModel** provides the same functionality in terms of reactivity using the Model class + notifyListeners().