# Is it possible listen state of many BloC?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

After asking about state management in Flutter ([Difference between ChangeNotifierProvider and ScopedModel in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56886805/difference-between-changenotifierprovider-and-scopedmodel-in-flutter)) without having any answer  I decided to use [BLoC Package](https://pub.dev/packages/bloc) which seems to me the clearest and easiest to use.
Now in my flutter app i have BlocA, BlocB and BlocC and I want to listen the state changes of BlocA and BlocB from BlocC.

Example with same states/event on all blocs (Updating,Updated/ Update):

```
class BlocC extends Bloc<CEvent, CState> {
  final BlocA a;
  final BlocB b;
  StreamSubscription aSubscription;

  BlocC({@required this.a, @required this.b}) {
    aSubscription = a.state.listen((state) {
      if (state is AUpdated) {
        dispatch(UpdateC());
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  CState get initialState => CUpdating();

  @override
  Stream<CState> mapEventToState(CEvent event) async* {
    if (event is UpdateC && b.currentState is BUpdated) {
      yield* CUpdated();
    }
  }
...
```

In this case when dispatching the event from BlocA state the state of BlocB sometimes isn't updated in the _mapEventToState method and my listener not work.
So I think there is a way to subscribe a bloc to many streams for get the correct state transition of all streams.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the expected behavior because you are dispatching `UpdateC()` only when the state of `BlocA` is `AUpdated`, and not when also the state of `BlocB` is `BUpdated`.

And even if your dispatching events that change the state of `BlocA` and `BlocB` to updated at the same time, this is asynchronous, so you are not warranted that `event is UpdateC && b.currentState is BUpdated` can be true ever. so you loss some `UpdateC` events.

For your case you can use [combineLastest2](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Observable/combineLatest2.html) of rxdart. And dispatch `UpdateC()` only when the `BlocA` and `BlocB` have the `Updated` state at the same time.

```dart
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class BlocC extends Bloc<CEvent, CState> {
  final BlocA a;
  final BlocB b;
  StreamSubscription<bool> _canUpdateCSubscription;

  BlocC({@required this.a, @required this.b}) {
    _canUpdateCSubscription = Observable.combineLatest2(
      a.state,
      b.state,
      (aState, bState) => aState is AUpdated && bState is BUpdated,
    ).listen(
      (canUpdateC) {
        if (canUpdateC) dispatch(UpdateC());
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _canUpdateCSubscription?.cancel();
    _canUpdateCSubscription = null;
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  CState get initialState => CUpdating();

  @override
  Stream<CState> mapEventToState(CEvent event) async* {
    if (event is UpdateC) {
      yield* CUpdated();
    }
  }
...
```

Comment: Good solution! But finally i decide for subscripe dispatching  of BlocB to BlocA state. So i have a cascade streams.